# How can i give values to variable that store in single array using loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I know this one

```
<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
asort($age);

foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
     echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
     echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

its output is just like

```
Key=Peter, Value=35
Key=Ben, Value=37
Key=Joe, Value=43
```

but let suppose I have an array which already contain variables which represents
keys like

```
$a="peter";
$b="Ben";
$c="Joe";
$a=array($a,$b,$c);
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
$a[$i]=>$i;
}
asort($a);

foreach($a as $x => $x_value) {
     echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
     echo "<br>";
}
```

but it does not work. I hope You guys can understand what is the problem. I want to give values using a loop

Comment: What is the output? And what output do you expect?

Comment: `print_r($a)` before pass to `foreach` and check

Comment: You _overwrite_ the array elements with keys 0, 1, 2, you do not use those values as keys somehow.

Comment: Syntax error: `$a[$i]=>$i;` should be `$a[$i]=$i;`. Not sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is replacing all the strings in the array with numbers. Nothing is converting the string into the key of the new entry.

If you want to convert the array from indexed to associative, you can do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $a[$a[$i]] = $i; // Add 'name' => $i
    unset($a[$i]); // Remove the original string
}
```